# Can not convert from object to list exception

Tags: spring-mvc

```
List<myJavaClass> smallListnew = (List<myJavaClass>) i1.next();
```

Above line causing error says object can not be type casted to type `List<myJavaClass>`.

Below is some description code:

```
List<myJavaClass> i1=bigList.iterator();
```

Big list contains many small list in the following way:

```
//here unique list contains some Long values without the duplicates that were being compared with the refreshJobCountList.
Iterator<Long> i=uniqueRefJobId.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Long refreshJobID = i.next();
    List<myJavaClass> smallList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (myJavaClass details : refreshJobCountList) {
        if (refreshJobID.equals(details.getRefreshJobId())) {
            myJavaClass new_obj=new myJavaClass();
            new_obj.setCount(details.getCount());
            new_obj.setJobRunId(details.getJobRunId());
            new_obj.setRefreshJobId(details.getRefreshJobId());
            smallList.add(new_obj);
        }
    }

    bigList.addAll(smallList);  
}
```

Comment: please provide solution, if any doubt regarding understanding this then please ask?

Comment: What type would `i1` be?

Comment: rather than typecasting, you could add the elements of the small list to the big list? `.addAll` would work?

Comment: Thanks @Alan for clarification.

Comment: @swati anytimee :) did it work that way?

Comment: yeah @Alan. It worked

Comment: do accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typecasting the array. Add the elements of the small list to a bigger list. Use `.allAll()` to add the entire list.